# Motivation behind action when deriving ''Strings as Harmonic oscillators" in Zwiebach's book on String theory

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, harmonic-oscillator, variational-principle, action

Page 248 gives us this action and he simply says that we will assume it correct.

$$
S=\int d \tau d \sigma ~\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{4 \pi \alpha^{\prime}} \int d \tau \int_{0}^{\pi} d \sigma\left(\dot{X}^{I} \dot{X}^{I}-X^{I^{\prime}} X^{I^{\prime}}\right),\tag{12.81}
 $$
where $X^I$ denote transverse target-space coordinates.

Besides giving us the right answer at the end, what is the motivation for this action, how was it thought up? It seems like a modified Nambu-Goto action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the simplest action of a field $X^I(\sigma,\tau)$ defined on a 2d worldsheet which is manifestly Lorentz invariant in target space. Your action is a special case of the Polyakov action where both the worldsheet metric $h^{ab}(\sigma,\tau)$ and the target space metric $g_{\mu \nu}(X)$ are taken to be flat.

Answer (score 3):

1. FWIW, it is in principle possible to systematically derive the light-cone action (12.81) from (the Hamiltonian formulation of) the [Nambu-Goto (NG) string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nambu%E2%80%93Goto_action), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184742/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. The NG action is in principle equivalent to the [Polyakov action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyakov_action), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268782/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. In both cases, it takes a bit of work to consistently reduce to the transverse degrees of freedom of the light-cone formulation (12.81).

Answer (score -1):

$$
\delta S=\int_{\tau_{i}}^{\tau_{f}} d \tau\left[\delta X^{\mu} \mathcal{P}_{\mu}^{\sigma}\right]_{0}^{\sigma_{1}}-\int_{\tau_{i}}^{\tau_{f}} d \tau \int_{0}^{\sigma_{1}} d \sigma \delta X^{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{P}_{\mu}^{\tau}}{\partial \tau}+\frac{\partial \mathcal{P}_{\mu}^{\sigma}}{\partial \sigma}\right)
 $$

$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{X}^{I}}=\frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha^{\prime}} \dot{X}^{I}=\mathcal{P}^{\tau I}
 $$

Then working in reverse to find the action. I'm not sure if it's cyclical or not but I don't like going the Hamiltonian way for the exact same reason.